# External tools stdout not shown during execution

Tags: python, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am calling python scripts from android studio as external tools.

Only after the script has exited, its stderr/stdout is displayed in the integrated Android Studio "Run" tool window. I want to be able to see the output during execution. (How) is that possible?

[image: edit external tools]

Answer (score 0):

Running Python in unbuffered mode (`-u`) fixxed it
- first Line of my python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 -u
```

Thanks for the solution to Serge Baranov from Jetbrains support:

> Sep 21, 16:23 MSK
>
> Could it be caused by the buffered output? See
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/230780/104891.